# How to find expiry date from current and given date

Tags: blackberry

I am working on the application which have 15days free subscription and then it give the expiry message to the user.
I got the expiry date (yyyy-MM-dd format) in login and have to check with current date .

I have tried with the two date object 1st object have current date and 2nd have expiry date.
But i am only get true when both date are same with `DateTimeUtilities.isSameDate(date1, date2);` function but it only return true if both date are same.

Please anyone help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer with the following

```
SimpleDateFormat  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//Your format type
Date todayDate = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(formatter.formatLocal(System.currentTimeMillis())));//It converts system date in your given format & store in todayDate object
Date expiryDate = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(expiryDateString));//It Store your expiry date in your expiryDate format
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(todayDate);
cal2.setTime(expiryDate);

if(cal1.before(cal2))
{
// Current date is less than your Expiry date
}
else
{
// Current date is equals and greater your Expiry date
}
```

Comment: don't you think using `HttpDateParser` and `Calendar` is a bit overkill? The parameterless `Date` constructor handles retrieving the local time for you, and you don't need a `Calendar` to compare two `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
boolean expired = (currentDate.getTime()>expiryDate.getTime());
if(expired)
    Status.show("Expired");
```

Comment: how are you filling in the two `Date` objects?

Comment: OP already tried date1,date2  so I assumed he has two date objects